# Why can't I access IsolatedStorage in the System.IO namespace?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, isolatedstorage

I am Running VisualStudio 2012 RC on Windows 8 Release Preview.

I am logged in to Win8 using my 'live' aka 'outlook' ID.

I created a new Windows Metro Style project. When I try to use System.IO.IsolatedStorage Visual Studio tells me that I am missing a reference. But when I go to references there is nothing to add and it says all references added by default.

Now as far as I can see IsolatedStorage is part of mscorlib.dll so it being 'missing' is unlikely.

What am I missing?

Thanks and Regards,
Sumit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IsolatedStorage is not part of .Net for WinRT.  You will have to use Windows.Storage.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#storage

Comment: Thanks, this is Interesting to say the least... I am currently waiting for VS to reinstall itself completely. Will circle back and let everyone know if the above resolves it. My skepticism stems from the fact that Linq2Twitter is built using System.IO.Localstorage. But I can't build it's code on my machine because of this error.

Comment: Thanks Gambit. You were correct, I was able to resolve my build issues using the suggestions above. 'Reinstall' wasn't the issue.